# Two notices Undefined variable where and search

Tags: php, search, where-clause

```
Notice: Undefined variable: where
Notice: Undefined variable: search
```

I get these two notices on all my pages.

How can I solve these?

Just added the input type.

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="<?= $search; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" />

<?php
if (!isset($page)) {
    $page = 1;
}
$view = 50;
$start = ($view * $page) - $view;
//
if (isset($search)) {    
    $where = "WHERE `first` LIKE '%$search%' OR `second` LIKE '%$search%'";
} 
$i = 0;    
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `first`, `second` FROM `table_one` $where ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT $start, $view");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
?>
```

Comment: Is that one contiguous piece of code? I mean, does `//` cover a missing bit of code? Are `$start`, `$view` and `$query` in the same scope?

Comment: Where does the `$search` variable come from? Does it get set somewhere else in your code, or are you using `register_globals` or something?

Comment: Yes, your right. I am adding it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($search)) {    
    $where = "WHERE `first` LIKE '%$search%' OR `second` LIKE '%$search%'";
}
```

This parts needs an else-statement or `$where` needs to have a default value. When `$search` is not set, `$where` will never be set.

```
$where = "";
if (isset($search)) {    
    $where = "WHERE `first` LIKE '%$search%' OR `second` LIKE '%$search%'";
}
```

Comment: Thnx! Yes, that fixes the $where notice.

Comment: I don't see any part of your code that would show the other notice. The notice should give you the line of code that produced it - are you sure that part is in your question?

Comment: On 1 page this solution isn't working and I get the next two errors if I go to a ?sub&page -> Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in line 999
 
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: This is no solution to said errors, but to the posted warnings. Generally problems with warnings or notices in PHP are quite easy to solve, since you usually get the corrupted line and an explanation what exactly went wrong, this makes debugging simple and doable